# FAST search - exclude property from hit highlighted summary

Tags: fast-search, managed-property

Is it possible to control what fields are included in the `hithighlightsummary` using FAST Search Server? I have some custom fields, which are stored as note in the special text format. I don't want to include them in `HitHighlightedSummary`, but I want them to be searchable at the same time. I gave thought to this matter and found some solutions, which would be helpful.

1. [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193926.aspx) describes how to control this feature via the managed property `SummaryType` parameter in the index schema. I followed all the necessary rules, reset index, made full crawling and got the same results. My custom fields were still in Summary.
2. Then I found [this article](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/11/10/find-me-but-dont-show-me/), it illustrates how to exclude the unwanted fields using `'ExcludeFromSummary'` managed property. This rule was described for SharePoint Search only, not for FAST. But I checked it for FAST Search too by exporting this property to FAST Search. Resetting index, full crawling....the same result. Custom fields were still in Summary.

The only information, that I have found about how `HitHighlightedSummary` is formed was

> "By default the hit highlighted summary is configured for the body and
>   title properties".

I checked these properties and didn't find any useful information to solve the problem. I couldn't understand, how my custom properties are displayed in the summary. May be I complicate matters and there is only one trick to hide them, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is any help to you?

[Removing unwanted properties from hithighlightedsummary in SharePoint FAST Search](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b460d6ce-7ebd-4a5e-8535-7c20713d0809/removing-unwanted-properties-from-hithighlightedsummary-in-sharepoint-fast-search?forum=fastsharepoint)

also look at this on msdn:

[Manage hit highlighted summary for a managed property by using Windows PowerShell (FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193926)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first link, that you provided, describes the method, which will remove the crawled property from the search index. This method will decrease the number of the results for the keyword. But the main aim is to remain the search results and hide the necessary custom properties from the summary. So, in other words, these properties should remain queriable. The second link is just similar to my first point, that I described in the question. So, no one from your suggestions achieved the goal.  But, anyway - thank you for your response.